# Can shear links be designed to hook between inner layers of top and bottom reinforcement?

Tags: structural-engineering, foundations

I am tasked to design a bridge pile cap. Shear links are required. However due to heavy reinforcement used, contractor requested to hook the links between inner rebars to ease construction. Is this allowed in British Standard? How should this be taken into consideration if it is allowed?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with a simple sketch demonstrating what you mean?